# selenium: locating an element within a WebDriver element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

It is a fact that I can locate the exact elements I want with this XPath:

```
//table[@class="summary-table"]/tbody/tr/*/*/*/a[contains(@class, "snippet-title")]
```

I know this because I have an XPath plugin that highlights 
detected elements.

I want to split this element traversal into two parts. The first
part returns a list of `tr` cells and the second part does a search in
each `tr` cells for the `a` within each one of interest.

The first part to return the `tr` cells is written and working:

```
  @property
  def product_elements(self):
    xpath = '//table[@class="summary-table"]/tbody/tr'
    elems = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
    return elems
```

However, I have tried various XPath and css selectors in the code
below:

```
  @property
  def product_names(self):
    xpath = '//a[contains(@class, "lc-snippet-title")]'
    for product_elem in self.product_elements:
      elem = product_elem.find_element_by_css_selector('.lc-snippet-title')
      logging.debug("Found this element {0}".format(
          self.pretty_printer.pformat(elem)))
      yield elem.text
```

and nothing is working to find the `a` that I want within the `tr`
WebDriver element.

Because there are multiple `a` tags within the `tr`, I must find the
one I want by the class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly about CSS selector, but if you have a WebElement with xpath `//table[@class="summary-table"]/tbody/tr` and it has a child `//a[contains(@class, "lc-snippet-title")]`, the next code works just fine for me:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class="summary-table"]/tbody/tr")
child = element.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[contains(@class, "lc-snippet-title")]")
```

The whole point is in `.` in the beginning of the child element's XPath locator which represents that it is actually a child. Try this

Answer (score 0):

Given Info:
XPath://table[@class="summary-table"]/tbody/tr/*/*/*/a[contains(@class, "snippet-title")]

Step 1:

Let us convert the above XPath to CSS Selector for Performance.

XPath://table[@class="summary-table"]/tbody/tr 
CSS:css=table.summary-table a.snippet-title > tbody > tr

Step 2:
Then we can find the CSS Count via given below method

@property

def product_elements(self):

css = 'css=table.summary-table > tbody > tr'

elems = self.driver.find_elements_by_by_css_selector(css)

return elems

@property

def product_names(self):

```
for product_elem in self.product_elements:
  elem = product_elem.find_element_by_css_selector('.lc-snippet-title')
  logging.debug("Found this element {0}".format(
      self.pretty_printer.pformat(elem)))
  yield elem.text
```